# Mess with Python directory and MySQL on Mac

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm learning how to connect Python with MySQL these days, but I'm really a rookie programmer and it's the first time for me to use MySQL.

I downloaded MySQL from the internet and followed the instructions from people to initialise MySQL by typing these codes below:

enter：vi .bash_profile

press a

enter： export PATH =/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$PATH

press esc

enter（：wq）

enter：PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/mysql/bin

enter：echo $PATH

If "/usr/local/mysql/bin” pops up then it's a success.

However, when I followed the instructions I only got:

-bash: export: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier

I suppose I've had something wrong with the Python directory, how can I fix this?

Comment: do you have a space after `export PATH`? It should be `export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$PATH`.

Comment: Aside: If you're a rookie, I recommend PostgreSQL as your first database. =)

Comment: Still doesn't work:(

Answer (score 1):

Remove the slash after `bin` in the line:

```
enter： export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$PATH
                                        ^
```

and try again

Comment: However, I don't think this is the issue. It must be with the space after `PATH` and before `=` in --> `export PATH =/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$PATH`. This is an invalid syntax.

Comment: I also think that it's invalid syntax but I suspect that he typed it directly in SO window, because the error message shows a valid path (only the extra slash - which, I suspect, causes the issue).